# Should I store common functions in a Parent/Base class

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, parent-child

I have common functions, such as syntactic sugar for calling the database, logging or site-wide information such as a look-up tables.

If I put these in a site-wide base class I will have access to them, however it just seems intuitively wrong to use a parent class this way. It would make more sense to use the base class as a 'has a' relationship rather than an 'is a'.

Or perhaps this is good design? Is there any problem doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent classes should instantiate some base functionality and a child should instantiate the differentiating code.

IMNSHO, what you are describing is a bastardization of that process.

Comment: Thank you. What constitutes as relevant 'base functionality'? Why would the described above not count?

Comment: Base functionality comprises the 'is a' that you refer to in your question.  for example, `Shape` is a parent class to `Square`, `Circle`, `Triangle` for instance.  `Setup` would not be a parent class to the aforementioned children because it doesn't define anything about their qualities.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would only want to serializable POCO classes, because they only contain properties and no methods.

Having a baseclass for common functionality might be a good idea, if you place code it in, that will be same in every childpage and if there is no other good place.

For instance you could place Helper-methods inside a baseclass, but that breaks OOP in my opinion.

In my opinion, having a class that derives from `System.Web.UI.Page` and replaces some logic in the `OnInit event` or other events is a very good strategy. I've used this approach in various projects, but I limited the code in the baseblass to globalization and logic for memberpages (like redirects to non public pages).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are doing is wrong.

First of all, object should be dedicated to one task. Having db connection handling, logging or look-up tables in the same class seems very ugly, regardless of whether these funcitonalities are inherited or not.

Moreover, the functionalities you described seem like fitting the exact idea of an object, just as described above. So, to answer your question: yes, has-a relationship seems like a much better solution.

In general, I tend to try to put program-wide accessible functions in separate classes. If possible, I try to use static methods. Behind these sometimes are singletons, sometimes there is some kind of queue, and sometimes something entirely different. Still, having one single point of origin for such functionalities the code is very flexible. If static methods are not applicable, especially when there is a need to store some information in such helper class, only then do I instantiate an object for each instance of other class. Even then factory/pool single point of origin static methods are often a good idea.